# error: libtool failed with exit code 1 on ad hoc build after integrating with OpenFeint

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, openfeint

I updated my iPhone game with OpenFeint and when I do a ad hoc build I am getting this error (simulator works fine):

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool: -dynamic not specified, -all_load invalid
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool: file: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib is a dynamic library, not added to the static library
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool: file: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib is a dynamic library, not added to the static library
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool: file: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib is a dynamic library, not added to the static library
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: AVFoundation (No such file or directory)
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1
```

Thoughts?